# Gnuplot generated by C program can't be rotated

Tags: c, gnuplot

I'm trying to create an interface with C that generates a surface plot that can be rotated. I've got C to generate the plot but it can't be rotated, any ideas? It seems like my program still has some sort of control over the process but I really don't know.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"

int main()
{
    FILE * temp = fopen("test.dat", "w");

    fprintf(temp, "set isosamples 100 \n");
    fprintf(temp, "set samples 100 \n");
    fprintf(temp, "unset key \n");
    fprintf(temp, "set title \"Something Test\" \n");
    fprintf(temp, "set xrange[-4:4] \n");
    fprintf(temp, "set yrange[-4:4] \n");
    fprintf(temp, "set ztics 1 \n");
    fprintf(temp, "unset surface \n");
    fprintf(temp, "set pm3d \n");
    fprintf(temp, "splot besj0(x**2+y**2) \n");
    fclose(temp);
    system("gnuplot -persist \"test.dat\"");

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't be rotated"?

Comment: I was able to use the mouse to change the angle of view of the 3d graph from the script you provide. Do you mean that the graph is rotating slowly by default at some initial velocity?

Comment: By "can't be rotated" I was referring to interactively rotating the graph using the mouse. If I manually enter the set of commands in gnuplot, a plot is generated that can be manipulated with the mouse. When it's created from my c program I cannot use the mouse to change the angle of view

Comment: i tested it, and it went OK according to your question, what you asked i got (and i just instaled gnuplot specifically to test this)

Comment: I also had no issues compiling and running the file and getting the expected behavior.

Comment: which version of gnuplot are you running?

Comment: I'm running gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6 on Centos 6.3. What configuration is it working on?

Comment: Dang it... Looks like it's a Centos issue. Works on Mandriva - crap!

Comment: It could have something to do with the version of gnuplot.  I believe that not too long ago (perhaps after your 4.2.6 version), gnuplot was given the ability to remember data that comes from stdin, in order to allow zooming and such.  Although, in your case, the data comes from a function rather than numbers on stdin so this probably doesn't apply.  Just to narrow it down a bit, do you get the same behavior when running "gnuplot -persist test.dat" from the command line?

Comment: I do get the same behaviour when I run "gnuplot -persist test.dat". I've upgraded to gnuplot 4.6 and still see the same issues.